# cross tabulation and data excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have data in a table "1" as follows:

```
"row"    "identifier 1"   "identifier 2"    "delta"

(1.2)     100              11               89

(3.14)     3               88               85

(6.41)    56              30                 26

...      ...             ...                ...
...      ...             ...                 ...
```

I have another table that makes the renamage of the "identifier 1" as follows:

```
"identifier 1 before renaming"            "identifier 1 after renemage"
   
       100                                            11
       3                                              88
       56                                             30
       ...                                            ..
```

My question how do I replace the values in column "identifier 1" of table 1 with these values corresponding to "identifier 1 after renemage"

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can joust use a [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) function to do a left join between the two tables.

Consider the following spreadsheet

```
+---+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+-------+------------------+
|   |               A                |              B              |      C       |   D   |        E         |
+---+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+-------+------------------+
| 1 | row                            | identifier 1                | identifier 2 | delta | New Identifier 1 |
| 2 | (1.2)                          | 100                         | 11           | 89    | 11               |
| 3 | (3.14)                         | 3                           | 88           | 85    |                  |
| 4 | (6.41)                         | 56                          | 30           | 26    |                  |
| 5 |                                |                             |              |       |                  |
| 6 | "identifier 1 before renaming" | identifier 1 after renemage |              |       |                  |
| 7 | 100                            | 11                          |              |       |                  |
| 8 | 3                              | 88                          |              |       |                  |
| 9 | 56                             | 30                          |              |       |                  |
+---+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+-------+------------------+
```

In the E2 cell you can just write the function: `=VLOOKUP(B2,$A$7:$B$9,2,0)`